# Find the limits of integration for a change of variables

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem with a double integral where I need to do a change of variables. The variable changes are

$$u=xy, \quad v=y/x$$

The original limits of integration are $y=0$ to $y=1$ and $x=y$ to $x=1/y$. I have no problem computing the Jacobian, changing $f(x,y)$ to $f(u, v)$ or actually doing the integration, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the new limits are in terms of $u$ and $v$. I've been told that I can plot the lines of constant $u$ and $v$ and overlay them onto the xy plane to see what the new limits are, but I'm not having any luck. I think it's the limit of $x=1/y$ that's really throwing me off.

Comment: What is the original problem? Context always helps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do the math markup on here. It's as a described above and the expression to evaluate is 
(y^3/x)exp[y^2(x^2+x^-2)]dxdy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We observe that the region of integration consists of horizontal strips of differential width $dy$ on the intervals $(y, 1/y)$ for each $y \in (0,1)$.  Under the mapping $u=xy$, $v = y/x$, the boundary $y = 1/x$ corresponds to $u = 1$ and the boundary $y = x$ corresponds to $v = 1$; the boundary $y = 0$ corresponds to both $u = 0$ and $v = 0$.  So our limits of integration should be $$\int_{u = 0}^1 \int_{v = 0}^1 f(u,v) |J| \, dv \, du.$$

[image]

Comment: That all makes a lot of sense. I think I got that answer at one point but dismissed it. I think the problem is that I'm having a hard time understanding how something that goes off to infinity on the right there in the xy plane turns into a nice neat finite rectangle in the uv plane.

Comment: @Chris Bennet  Try thinking about where some specific points on the boundaries get sent in the $uv$-plane.  The point (2,1/2) is on the curve $y=1/x$.  It gets sent to $(1,4)$ in the $uv$-plane.  The point $(3,3)$ is on the curve $y=x$.  It gets sent to $(9,1)$ in the $uv$-plane.